# Adding mysql data as td attribute with php

Tags: php, mysqli

I need this code to give me a little different output.

```
 <?php

$conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }


function print_tableA ($conn, $id) {
    $sql = "SELECT Value1, Value2, Value3, Value4, Value5, Value6, Value7, Value8 FROM mytable1";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        echo "<table id='$id'>";
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo '<tr><td>' . join('</td><td>', $row) . "</td></tr>\n" ;
        }
        echo "</table>";
    }
}  


$result = $conn->query("SELECT Date from mytable2");
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    print_tableA ($conn, $row['Date']);
}

?>
```

Currently it prints the output in this format: `

```
<tr>
<td>2</td> 
....
</tr>`
```

I need it to be printed in this format:

```
<tr>
<td val="2">2</td>
....
</tr>
```

so basically the data from the mysql should also be repeated as a td attribute. I hope this is simple, and I'd be grateful if someone can show me the change that I need to make to get this output. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `while` loop with this one:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
   $data = array_reduce($row, function($carry, $value) {
               $carry[] = "<td val='{$value}'>{$value}</td>";
               return $carry;
           }, []);

  echo '<tr>' . implode('', $data) . "</tr>\n" ;
}
```

will output:

```
<tr><td val='10'>10</td><td val='11'>11</td></tr>
```

A sendbox example can be found [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fa643cf80f089be9bd8e0ef43abd9bfaa21495d0).

PHP Manual for [`array_reduce`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) function.

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate through the row values and echo the td as you want them:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo '<tr>';

    // Let's iterate through all the columns
    foreach ($row as $value) {
        echo "<td val='$value'>$value</td>";
    }

    echo "</tr>\n";
}
```

Just as a note: `val` isn't a valid attribute in for a `td`-element.